# How do you host a React app with a Node backend on Heroku?

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

I'm trying to host a React app created with `create-react-app` on a Heroku instance. It has API calls from a Node backend that I also need to be hosted.

I have asked around and people state to serve the files built from the React app as static files using the `express` middleware. I'm not sure what that entails and all of my tries with it have led to application errors. I'm not quite sure if I need to host the built files

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('~/Developer/JavaScript/Vue/fffreact/build'));
}
```

This is what I am currently using (probably improperly) to serve the static files that I've built.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `create-react-app` build script you get a build folder. This is the folder you want to tell express to serve statically. Then you have a catch all route handler which will always send back the `index.html` which is found in the build folder. See the following example.

```
if (process.env.PROD) {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './frontend/build')));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './frontend/build/index.html'));
    });
}
```

The `__dirname` will get the FULL path till the file you are currently in, and from there you can just use the relative path to the build folder.

Comment: Didn't work. Am I supposed to put my frontend app inside the same directory as my backend?

Comment: that's what I usually do. It would also be advised since on Heroku you have no control over where the frontend dir might be.

Comment: If you have a node/express backend with your react frontend - heroku expects your server files to be in the root and your frontend files in a frontend folder. Make sure you have only one git folder in the root of the application and not in the frontend folder as well. You need to add a script to your package.json: "heroku-postbuild":"NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false cd frontend && npm install && npm run build"